# PhpStorm cannot Ctrl+Click open JavaScript factory file

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm, webstorm

We am working with PhpStorm IDE, which can understand a lot of instructions with our programming language. In PHP when we have a `Factory` like `getService` which provide us an object of a service from a specific file, we use [`.phpstorm.meta.php`](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata) file to help PhpStorm understand what will go on when we <kbd>CTRL+Click</kbd> on it .

But in JavaScript when we have an `.init(service)` method, we do not know how we could tell PhpStorm to open that file when <kbd>Ctrl+click</kbd> or knowing methods in that `service`. Our `init` method looks something like :

```
var OurMainClass = {

    getServiceFileAndLoadIt : function(file , after){
        // load file

        // call after load function
    }

    init : function(service){
        OurMainClass.getServiceFileAndLoadIt(service , function(serviveObject){
            return serviveObject;
        });
    },

};
```

Do we have some configuration file like `phpstorm.meta.js` ?

Comment: Nope -- there is no equivalent functionality for JavaScript. Maybe some another mechanics .. but nothing like that metadata for PHP.

Comment: for javascript, code navigation is based on javascript index that includes all `.js` and `d.ts` project files + libraries (see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/). No special metadata exists. If the method can be resolved with static code analysis, the IDE can jump to it on `Ctrl+click`